# Wordpress - Display Limited Post From A Specific Category

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress i need to display post on home page from a specific category.

- Need Five Post With Title
- Category Is News
- Display On Main home page

i use plugin business news but when i activate this plugin nex gen gallery plugin will be conflict now i dont know how to resolve this please suggest.

Comment: Have a look at [ask] plz...

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to display post of a specific category. To display on home page, you will have to make following changes in your index.php file.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('category_name'=>'news', 'posts_per_page'=> '5') ); 
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
       while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
             get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
       endwhile; 
  endif;
```